# Can you help me fix the average portion of my code?

Tags: java, average

When I run this code and input numbers whose sum>100 the output is correct for the count and the sum but the average is wrong. For example; input 8,10,99... the count is 3, the sum is 117 and should return an average of 39... the actual output returned is count 3, sum 117 and average 58.5. I have come to realize this is because the average is being done using a count of 2 instead of 3(or always one less than it should be with different values). Why is this? It works perfect for inputs sum<=100. PLEASE HELP :)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Use Main Method for gathering input
    float input = 1;
    // Declare variable for sum
    float theSum = 0;
    // Declare variable for average
    float average = 0;
    // Declare variable for counting the number of user inputs
    int counter = 0;
    /* Initialize the while loop using an input of 0 as a sentinel value
     * to exit the loop*/
    while (input != 0) {
        // Use JOptionPane method to accept input from user
        input = Float.parseFloat(
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null, "Please enter a number.  Enter 0 to quit: "));
        // Invoke sum method and pass input and summation to sum method
        theSum = (sum(input, theSum));
        // Invoke avg method and pass summation and counter to avg
        average = (avg(theSum, counter));
        // Increment the counter variable
        counter++;

        if (theSum > 100)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of your numbers "
                    + "are greater than 100!");
            break;
        }
    }
        // Invoke display method and pass summation, average, and counter variables to it
        display(theSum, average, counter);
    }


public static float sum(float num1, float sum) {
    //Add the user's input number to the sum variable
    sum += num1;
    //Return value of sum variable as new summation variable
    return sum;
}

public static float avg(float num1, int num2) {
    //Declare and initialize variable for average
    float average = 0;
    //Calculate average
    average = num1 / num2;
    //Return value of average variable
    return average;
}

public static void display(float sum, float average, int counter) {

    /* I am subtracting 1 from variable counter so as not to include the sentinel value
     * of 0 that the user had to enter to exit the input loop in the overall count*/

    // Display the count, sum, and average to the user
    if (sum > 100) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Count = " + (counter) + ", Sum = " + sum + ", Average = " + average);
    }
    if (sum <= 100) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Count = " + (counter - 1) + ", Sum = " + sum + ", Average = " + average);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You increment the counter *after* taking average, which is why you see your average based on 2 numbers rather than your expected 3.

```
    average = (avg(theSum, counter));
    // Increment the counter variable
    counter++;
```

Swap those two and increment counter *before* you take average.

```
    counter++;
    // Increment the counter variable
    average = (avg(theSum, counter));
```

**Edit:**

Here is what you should change:

First, update the counter only if input is not = 0

```
    if(input!=0)
    {
    counter++;
    }
```

Secondly, move the average code out of the loop and it put it in the end just before display, don't need to compute average again and again.

```
    average = (avg(theSum, counter));
    display(theSum, average, counter);
```

Thirdly,  remove `counter-1` from `display` method and print `counter`

```
public static void display(float sum, float average, int counter) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Count = " + (counter) + ", Sum = " + sum + ", Average = " + average);
 }
```

After that, it works for both cases like you expect

Comment: Thank You!!!!! I've been going CRAZY!!! Worked like a charm, you're the best :)

Comment: BUUUUTTTT, now the average of the input with sum<=100 is wrong... any ideas?

Comment: Chris you need to remove this: (counter - 1) from your messagedialog. Do the same thing no matter what your sum is.

Comment: the counter-1 is to account for the "0 to exit" I didn't want it included in the count... either way. I still got the same wrong output :( when I input 8,10,19 the sum is 37 and the returned average is 9.25. It should be 12.33333. Oddly the output is the same regardless of the -1.

Comment: This didn't work either?

Comment: Works fine for me in both cases